# Configuring OpenCV with Python on Mac, but failed to compile

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, opencv

I was trying to configure the OpenCV with Python 2.7 on a MacOSX environment, I use the Homebrew to install OpenCV, and it works perfect with C++, but when I attempted to compile a python file by typing `python test.py`, it gives me the error saying that

```
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
import cv ImportError: No module named cv
```

I tried the solution by adding `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH` into `.bash_profile` for my home folder.

However, it does not solve my compiling issue.

Any solution for this issue? Thanks.

Comment: I have installed OpenCV just to aid your question, and I didn't have any problem. I've tried first to do `brew install homebrew/science/opencv`, then it told me I have unmet Python dependency - `numpy`, that I have to install myself. I did it with `sudo pip install numpy`, then I had retried `brew install`, and after building `eigen`, `jpeg`, `libtiff`, `ilmbase` and `openexr` dependencies it did install fine. Doing `import cv` in python 2.7 works okay, `cv.__file__` shows `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.pyc`.

Comment: `sudo pip install numpy` solves my issue, thank you!

Comment: Well, surprising how did homebrew let you go through it without installing `numpy` first - like it did in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to solution found in comments, it's because you have unmet `numpy` dependency. Use following:

```
sudo pip install numpy
brew install opencv
```